# Entity Framework и юнит тесты

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, юнит-тесты

Доброго времени суток!

У меня есть такой вопрос: у меня есть веб-прриложение asp.net mvc которое работает с базой данных через Entity Framework.

Для работы с Entity я создал класс-провайдер выполняющий стандартные CRUD операции. Хотелось бы все это дело покрыть юнит тестами как у крутых мужиков. Но слышал что юнит тесты не должны работать с базой данных. И это вроде как логично - допустим я хочу потестировать операции вставки, обновления и удаления у своего  репозитория но будет странно если тестовый код будет осуществлять эти операции с реальной базой (пусть даже и тестовой).

Пример теста с использованием Moq найденный на просторах интернета

```
// интерфейс репозитория
interface IRepository : IDisposable
{
    List<Computer> GetComputerList();
    Computer GetComputer(int id);
    void Create(Computer item);
    void Update(Computer item);
    void Delete(int id);        
}

 // тестовый метод
[TestMethod]
public void IndexViewBagMessage()
{        
    var mock = new Mock<IRepository>();
    mock.Setup(a => a.GetComputerList()).Returns(new List<Computer>() { new Computer()});
     // какая то логика тестирования
}
```

Но тогда возникает вопрос - а какой у этого всего смысл? Ведь в моке мы подставляем фейковые данные. То есть я вроде кк хочу протестировать работу моего репозитория а вместо этого методы самого репозитория не используются, а вместо них используются подставные данные из мока.

Отсюда вопрос: как все же правильно будет тестировать репозиторий и в чем смысл найденного мной примера?

Comment: Код свой приведите.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Смысл вашего примера — тестирование работы куска кода, который работает *с репозиторием*. Для него репозиторий подменяется на фейк.

Для тестирования самого репозитория вам нужно фейкнуть то, с чем он работает — то есть, базу данных. Тестируйте настоящий репозиторий на тестовой базе данных, ничего плохого в этом не вижу.

В любом случае, для «вертикальной» структуры приложения, если вы тестируете уровень *X*, вы в тестах подставляете фейковые нижележащие структуры данных/объекты (которые эмулируют уровень *X* + 1), а вышележащие объекты (то есть, те, которые работают с вашим уровнем *X*), заменяются на код теста.

Answer (score 2):

Тесты делятся на две основные категорий:

**Автоматизированые** - это тесты, которые ни от чего не зависят, они пишутся и выполняются быстрее.

**Интеграционные** - это тесты, которые зависят от внешний среды (БД, Файловая система, Сеть).

Для того, чтобы протестировать класс Repository, вам нужно создать заглушку для DbContext, который используется внутри класс Repository.